# Wrong (too much) vertical space above \vdots in small matrix

Tags: spacing, amsmath, matrices

If one uses `\vdots` in a `smallmatrix`-environment the vertical spacing above the dots is too large. It is the same spacing as in a normally sized `matrix`-environment.

Minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage{icomma}
%\usepackage[final]{microtype}
%\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{mathdots}

\begin{document}

Normally sized vector
\begin{equation}
\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ \vdots \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

Small vector with too much vertical spacing above the dots.
\begin{equation}
\left(\begin{smallmatrix} 0 \\ \vdots \\ 0 \end{smallmatrix}\right)
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

(In the end, I need all the packages above, but the error already occurs in the minimal setup.)

How do I reduce the spacing (for now)? Is it eventually a package implementation error? Should I report upstream?

Answer (score 14):

the latex definition of `\vdots` is identical to the one defined by knuth in `plain.tex`, except that it is made robust.
it is constructed from three periods stacked one above the other in a `\vbox`.
the "extra" space at the top is the consequence of the full height of a "normal" character
being used for the topmost period, whereas the actual height is much less.

here is a hack that smashes the `\vdots` and substitutes a vertical phantom of a height
that yields a more pleasing result.  unfortunately, i couldn't find just a single
substitution that works equally well in both situations.

```
\begin{document}

Normally sized vector
\begin{equation}
\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ \vphantom{\int^0}\smash[t]{\vdots} \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

Small vector with too much vertical spacing above the dots.
\begin{equation}
\left(\begin{smallmatrix} 0 \\
 \vphantom{\int\limits^x}\smash{\vdots} \\
 0 \end{smallmatrix}\right)
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image: output of example code]

Comment: OK, thanks. I am not sticked to use `\vdots`. If there is an alternative command (e.g. from another package) does not have the drawbacks of Knuth's orginal implementation, I am glad to use that. Actually, I am using the font Libertine (rm font), Biolinum (sf font) and Consolas (tt font) together with the newmathtx package. Libertine is also used as math font and it has a special unicode character for vertical dots. Is there any way to actual use that font symbol instead of an composed character out of three dots?