# Why does whitespace above \vdots disappear in bmatrix?

Tags: tikz-pgf, amsmath, matrices, tikz-matrix

While creating presentations with beamer, I have the problem described in 
[broken matrix gaps in brackets](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23431/broken-matrix-gaps-in-brackets). Using the solution proposed by Loop 
Space, I discovered that `\vdots` have an annoying whitepsace in tikz matrices (wich is also discussed [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/207056/wrong-too-much-vertical-space-above-vdots-in-small-matrix)).

Now I wonder, why those whitespaces are not displayed when you use the standard `bmatrix`
and how I can avoid these whitespaces in the tikz matrix.

Here is a MWE that shows the difference:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={draw}, baseline=(dots)]
\matrix [draw=red]
{
    \node{Hallo}; \fill[blue!50] (0,0) circle (2pt); \\
    \fill[blue!50] (0,0) circle (2pt); \node(dots) {$\vdots$}; \\
    \node{g}; \fill[blue!50] (0,0) circle (2pt); \\
};
\end{tikzpicture}
$
\begin{bmatrix}
    \text{Hallo} \\
    \vdots \\
    \text{g}
\end{bmatrix}
$
\end{document}
```

Which results

[image: Difference between vdots in tikz matrix and bmatrix]

Comment: Try comparing the second matrix with the one you get typing `\text{world}` in the middle row: you'll see the vertical space inserted by `\vdots` as well.

Comment: OK, so there still is whitespace in the `bmatrix`, and the `\vdots` don't look perfectly centered if you write an uppercase letter below it. But how is the spacing computed in the `bmatrix` then? For usage with the tikz matrix I implemented a solution by redefining the `\vdots` command: 
`\renewcommand{\vdots}
{
\tikz{
\fill(0,0)rectangle++(0.75pt,0.75pt);
\fill(0,4pt)rectangle++(.75pt,.75pt);
\fill(0,8pt)rectangle++(.75pt,.75pt);
}
}` which works perfect in the tikz matrix. Unfortunatelly, using it in the `bmatrix` leads to an asymetric (shifted up) placement of the dots.

Comment: Maybe you can use http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/112212/4427

Comment: This is the non-tikz re-implementation of the vdots command, I really like it, thanks for that. So now I have a command to use in the tikz matrices but the problem with `bmatrix` remains. The dots look good in tikz, but why are they somehow shifted upwards in `bmatrix`?

Answer (score 5):

Since the question was "why," the following shows that the baseline for \rvdots is at the bottom.  Note that `\vcenter` does not center relative to the baseline, but relative to the `\strut`.

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}


\DeclareRobustCommand{\rvdots}{%
  \vbox{%
    \baselineskip=4pt
    \lineskiplimit=0pt
    \kern-1pt
    \hbox{.}\hbox{.}\hbox{.}
  }}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\cvdots}{%
  \vcenter{%
    \baselineskip=4pt %spacing
    \hbox{.}\hbox{.}\hbox{.}
  }}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={scale=5,anchor=base,draw=red,inner sep=0pt}]
 \draw[blue] (0,0) -- (4,0);% baseline
 \node at (1,0) {$\rvdots$};
 \node at (2,0) {$\cvdots$};
 \node at (3,0) {\strut};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: dots nn baseline]

Comment: Thanks for that, it's interesting, as it shows that `\rvdots` actually are not perfectly centered in the tikz matrix (because the frame in the left picture doesnt include the upper "."). 
This leads me to a tikz-based solution for the `\vdots` again. I reworked it as `\renewcommand{\vdots}{
 \tikz[baseline, every node/.style={inner sep=0}]{
 \node at (0,0){.};
 \node at (0,4pt){.};
 \node at (0,8pt){.};
 }
 }` so it really uses font-dependend dots. But still the question about how elements are placed in the `bmatrix` remains open. Is it just "baselines in fixed distances"?