# Vertical dots in \substack

Tags: vertical-spacing, substack

I need to stack a large number of expressions below a sum sign. Using `\substack` and `\vdots` as in the code below
`\sum_{\substack{a_1  \in  A_1\\ \vdots  \\  a_k  \in A_k}}`
gives a pretty awful result, as the vertical dots are much closer to the bottom line than to the top one.
Is there a  way to center the dots between the two lines?
I tried to use `\mathstrut` to increase a little bit the spacing between the dots and the bottom line, but the increase is too small and apparently it does not stack up when repeating the command.

Comment: An answer given here might be helpful: [Wrong (too much) vertical space above \vdots in small matrix](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/207056)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want smaller and less spaced dots. Here's a way, which mimicks the definition of `\vdots`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\svdots}{%
  \vbox{\fontsize{\sf@size}{\sf@size pt}\linespread{0.3}\selectfont
    \kern0.2\baselineskip
    \hbox{.}\hbox{.}\hbox{.}%
    \kern0.1\baselineskip
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\[
\sum_{\substack{a_1  \in  A_1\\ \svdots  \\  a_k  \in A_k}}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It actually looks even better. Grazie, leggenda!

Answer (score 2):

You can fine-tune vertical spacing after `\\` with `\\[...]` like:

```
\sum_{\substack{a_1  \in  A_1\\[-4pt] \vdots  \\[2pt]  a_k  \in A_k}}
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: Wow, thank you very much!