# How to create a simple vertical vector with several vertical curly braces outside the square bracket?

Tags: arrays, brackets, mathtools, braces, vertical

I could not code a vertical vector with several vertical curly braces outside the square bracket of the vector. The best thing I have obtained so far is by using `rcases` from `mathtools` package that gives me a vertical vector with the corresponding vertical curly braces inside the square bracket of the vector. My code is as the following:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
    \mathcal{O}(t) = \left[ \begin{array}{c}
    \begin{rcases} c_1^\top \\ \vdots \\ c_p^\top \end{rcases}C\\ \begin{rcases} c_1^\top A \\ \vdots \\ c_p^\top A \end{rcases} CA \\ \vdots \\ \begin{rcases}c_1^\top A^{t-1} \\ \vdots \\ c_p^\top A^{t-1}\end{rcases} CA^{t-1}
    \end{array}\right].
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

that gives me this output:
[image]

which is still not accepted. Any hints that can help me to bring out the vertical curly braces would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Off topic: since `mathtools` loads `amsmath`, it's not necessary to load the latter separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `\vphantom` to replicate the vertical space of an object and use that together with a `\left.`...`\right\}` construction to simulate an `\rcases`-like environment:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\[
  \mathcal{O}(t) = \left[ \begin{array}{ c }
    \begin{array}{ @{} c @{} }
      c_1^\top \\ \vdots \\ c_p^\top
    \end{array} \\[1.5\normalbaselineskip]
    \begin{array}{ @{} c @{} }
      c_1^\top A \\ \vdots \\ c_p^\top A
    \end{array} \\
    \vdots \\
    \begin{array}{ @{} c @{} }
      c_1^\top A^{t - 1} \\ \vdots \\ c_p^\top A^{t - 1}
    \end{array}
  \end{array}\right]
  \begin{array}{ @{} l @{} }
    \left.\hskip-\nulldelimiterspace\vphantom{\begin{array}{ @{} c @{} }
      c_1^\top \\ \vdots \\ c_p^\top
    \end{array}}\right\} C \\[1.5\normalbaselineskip]
    \left.\hskip-\nulldelimiterspace\vphantom{\begin{array}{ @{} c @{} }
      c_1^\top A \\ \vdots \\ c_p^\top A
    \end{array}}\right\} CA \\
    \vphantom{\vdots} \\
    \left.\hskip-\nulldelimiterspace\vphantom{\begin{array}{ @{} c @{} }
      c_1^\top A^{t - 1} \\ \vdots \\ c_p^\top A^{t - 1}
    \end{array}}\right\} CA^{t - 1}
  \end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```

A slight horizontal correction (`\hskip-\nulldelimiterspace`) reduces the space between the array and the row indicators.

Comment: You might take a look at this question regarding the spacing around `\vdots`: [Wrong (too much) vertical space above \vdots in small matrix](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/207056)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `nicematrix` (with a little visual formatting).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\[
\mathcal{O}(t)=\;\;
\begin{NiceMatrix}
c_1^T & \Block[l]{3-1}{\ C} \\ \vdots \\ c_p^T \\[1ex]
c_1^TA & \Block[l]{3-1}{\ CA} \\ \vdots \\ c_p^TA \\
\vdots \\
c_1^TA^{t-1} & \Block[l]{3-1}{\ CA^{t-1}} \\ \vdots \\ c_p^TA^{t-1}
\CodeAfter
  \SubMatrix[{1-1}{10-1}]
  \SubMatrix.{1-1}{3-1}\}[xshift=3pt]
  \SubMatrix.{4-1}{6-1}\}[xshift=3pt]
  \SubMatrix.{8-1}{10-1}\}[xshift=3pt]
\end{NiceMatrix}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]